# Deleting points on width tool not working illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6

I'm having trouble with selecting points using the width tool. Sometimes I want to click and delete a point I don't want but sometimes it doesn't work and sometimes it adds a new point its very frustrating is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply horribly inaccurate in CS6.

That was the first iteration of the feature and some of it, such as selecting and deleting width markers is pretty bad. You just have to deal with it in CS6.

It *does* get better in newer versions.

<sub>(One can use the [VectorScribe](https://astutegraphics.com/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI77T5-_bI8gIV1Rt9Ch0QFALAEAAYASAAEgKrM_D_BwE) plugin [$$], which is much much much more accurate - but I believe they've discontinued CS6 support, so you had have bought it a year or so ago.)</sub>